# Entity Framework Code First - Explaination on assigning a list of proxy entities to an ICollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I am trying to assign a subset of data to a navigation property which is an ICollection of Bars and output the results. When I output the results all the data is returned, but when I debug and observe the assignment only the subset is outputted. I am expected only the subset to be outputted. Code is below.

Does anyone understand why this is happening. The fix is to clear the collection before assignment, but I would like to understand why this is happening in the first place. Perhaps this has to do with the ObjectStateManager?

Any ideas are appreciated :D

EF.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace CollectionsAssignmentOperator
{
    public class Bar
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int FooId { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
    }

    public class FooBarDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public FooBarDbContext()
            : base("FooBar")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<FooBarDbContext>(new SeedData());
        }

        public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
    }

    public class SeedData : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<FooBarDbContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(FooBarDbContext context)
        {
            var bars = new List<Bar>()
            {
                new Bar()
                {
                    Value = "Bar Test 1"
                },
                new Bar()
                {
                    Value = "Bar Test 2"
                },
                new Bar()
                {
                    Value = "Bar Test 3"
                }
            };

            var foo = new Foo()
            {
                Value = "Foo Test 1",
                Bars = bars
            };

            context.Foos.Add(foo);
            context.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace CollectionsAssignmentOperator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestCollectionAssignmentOperatorWithEntityFramework();

        }

        private static void TestCollectionAssignmentOperatorWithEntityFramework()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TestEntityCollectionAssignmentOperatorWithEntityFramework");

            List<Foo> foos;

            var context = new FooBarDbContext();

            foos = context.Foos.ToList();


            foreach (var foo in foos)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(foo.Value);

                //When I observe foo.Bars there are 3

                var bars = context.Bars.Where(bar => bar.FooId == foo.Id && bar.Value.Contains("2"));
                //When I observe bars there is one

                //foo.Bars.Clear(); //This consistently allows only the subset of data to be assigned.

                //When I observe the following there is now one foo.Bars
                foo.Bars = bars.ToList();

                foreach (var bar in foo.Bars.OrderBy(bar => bar.Id))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", "\t", bar.Value);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Results when ran:

```
TestEntityCollectionAssignmentOperatorWithEntityFramework
Foo Test 1
    Bar Test 1
    Bar Test 2
    Bar Test 3
```

Results when debugged and observing the results:

```
TestEntityCollectionAssignmentOperatorWithEntityFramework
Foo Test 1
    Bar Test 2
```

Comment: You are filtering `bars` to be one element with `&& bar.Value.Contains("2")` in your `Where` statement, so everythhing works correctly.

Comment: It is true that I am filtering bars to be one element, and I am expecting only 'Bar Test 2' to be written to the console. However, all the Bar's values are written to the console when I run the app, but when I debug the app and observe the collections, then only 'Bar Test 2' is written to the console.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the post for the first time. This is an interesting case, I thing it is connected to lazy loading, when you remove `virtual` from `Bars` in `Foo` it will always work as expected. My guess here, maybe because you are lazy loading, when you hit `foo.Bars` for the first time in inner foreach it will be loaded from db (previous change was memory-only. It's hard to explain though why forcing `bars` to be resolved with debugger works and with `.ToList()` does not.

Comment: That makes sense . So after the assignment, I loop through Bars at which point the DB query is executed and repopulates the collection.